# R - Matching strings to dictionary and replacing

Tags: r, ggplot2, replace, match

I making bar charts in R and want to change the x-axis strings using a dictionary that I have defined containing more readable names. Here is an example of the code.

```
    mydata
      name  value
      <chr>  <dbl>
    1 jd        20
    2 mk        30
    3 js        40

    readable_strings <- c("John Smith" = "js", "Jane Do" = "jd", "Mike Tyson" = "mt")
    ggplot(mydata, aes(x = name, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I would like the readable names to be displayed along the x-axis.  What is the best way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
# reverse the vector
convert_vec <- names(readable_strings)
names(convert_vec) <- readable_strings

# replace the values and plot
mydata$name <- sapply(mydata$name, function(x) convert_vec[[x]])
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = name, y=values)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```